# Scaling & Translating Graphics2D to Fit Rectangle

Tags: java, camera, scaling, graphics2d, translate

I'm working on a game in Java, and I'm having some trouble with camera movement and scaling. I've already made a Rectangle that shows exactly where I want the camera to be, and at what scale:
[image]
However, whenever I try to move the camera where I want it to be, I get weird results. The camera goes in weird places when I get to a point where the scale isn't 1:
[image]
Right now I have a camera class, where I set the position with:

```
x=-((leftX+Math.abs(leftX-rightX)/2)-Main.WINDOW_WIDTH/2/scale);
y=-((topY+Math.abs(topY-bottomY)/2)-Main.WINDOW_HEIGHT/2/scale);
```

Where leftX,rightX,topY, and bottomY are the topmost,rightmost,topmost,and bottommost points respectively. (I'm pretty sure scaling is working fine, so it shouldn't be necessary to include the code for it)

For translating and scaling, I have this:

```
g.translate(cam.getX(), cam.getY());
g.scale(cam.scale, cam.scale);

//Render in-game objects

g.translate(-cam.getX(), -cam.getY());
g.scale(1/cam.scale,1/cam.scale);
```

What I'm asking is, how can I move the camera so that it's perfectly aligned with the rectangle?